# Getting visible text from a QTextEdit in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit

This is related to another question I found here that seems to be inactive for a few months, so I think it's worth asking again.

I have created a simple QDialog that has a QTextEdit and a QPushButton. This pops up in my application when a user right-clicks and selects the option to "add comments". I want them to be able to write free-form text and I'll just save whatever they write as a long string with no concern for new lines, etc.

When the user clicks the button, it executes code like this:

```
    self.connect(accept_button,QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),lambda arg=str(view_textedit.toPlainText()): self.updateGroupComments(arg))

def updateGroupComments(self,new_comment_str):
    print "Updating user comment to have new string: " + new_comment_str
    self.group_entry.list_of_user_comments[self.currentFrameCounter] = new_comment_str
```

This is not detecting the TextEdit text that is visible (it only detects whatever the text edit text is set to when it is created). How do I make a simple command that returns the currently visible text from a QTextEdit. Again, the function

```
toPlainText()
```

is not working correctly... it doesn't find the currently visible text, only whatever text was on screen before changes or additions started being made by the user.

If this can't be done without subclassing and appealing to cursor positions, it makes the whole thing seem worthless... so please keep suggestions only to those implemented without subclassing or manipulating cursors. It should be really simple and straightforward to just return all currently visible text... what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects that are being bound to default arguments are evaluated at the definition time. The function *is* working correctly, it returns whatever was in the text field when it was executed. Your code simply calls it at the wrong moment. If you want to use lambda, then do:

```
self.connect(
    accept_button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),
    lambda: self.updateGroupComments(str(view_textedit.toPlainText()))
)
```

Or make `view_textedit` an instance attribute instead, and do simply

```
self.connect(
    accept_button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.updateGroupComments
)
```

And change `updateGroupComments` to call `self.view_textedit.toPlainText` instead of taking an argument.

BTW, this is not PyQt specific, this is how Python works in general.

To illustrate my last comment, that lambda can very well be replaced with:

```
def slot():
    self.updateGroupComments(str(view_textedit.toPlainText()))

self.connect(accept_button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), slot)
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide a link that explains why lambda: doesn't need to have the argument specified? How does lambda allow a slot called with arguments to become syntactically correct when there is not variable indicated as the argument? Making this change fixes my error, but it causes me to be more confused.

Comment: I get the lambda closure. What I don't get is how a bound object representing a single function call can be viewed as a valid slot for the connect() function in PyQt. If I can't do that for a regular function call with well-defined argument, why can I do it for a bound function call with the same well-defined argument? Is this literally just a convention of PyQt that is just happens to make the special exception when the function call is bound?

Comment: @EMS: I'm not sure I understand what you don't understand. ;) Any callable can be a slot, AFAIK PyQt. `clicked()` signal has no arguments, so the slot cannot take any non-default arguments either. Bound methods are special only in the way that they don't require you to repeat `self` argument (`self.foo()` is equivalent to `Class.foo(self)`).

Comment: In my code, I am passing this: self.updateGroupComments(str(view_textedit.toPlainText()), which is a function (with a specific argument), as a slot in the connect() function. If I remove the lambda: in front of it, though, it suddenly becomes an error because you can't pass named arguments in a slot. You can specify what function to call as the slot, but not with the arguments already in it. I'm just puzzled why the lambda: makes this syntactically ok... it feels like magic which is not good.

Comment: My point is: there's nothing inside that lambda expression that says, "Hey, wait until this argument gets filled in and then send this slot and this argument on which to evaluate the slot function". It's just a plain old function call with argument already inside. My question, I guess, is whether there is an overloaded version of the connect function that just accepts these lambda closed functions as the third argument. If so, then it's just a special Qt convention, rather than a generic way to simulate two arguments where only one is accepted in Python.

Comment: @EMS: It's a function call, so when you remove `lambda`, you are passing the *result* of that call to `connect`. It becomes an error more likely because `updateGroupComments` returns `None` and `None` is not callable. When you use `lambda`, you create a new function that is passed to `connect` and then called later by the signal/slot machinery. This has nothing to do with PyQt, it's Python basics, really, and no magic is involved. See my edit — you can use normal inner named function instead of an anonymous one with no problem.

Comment: I see. It's the part about a function returning None type that I failed to understand. It makes sense then since the lambda operation creates a function that returns a function call with argument, whereas just sticking a function with argument there that returns None tries to remove the SLOT middleman which doesn't work in PyQt. I think you're still believing it's just the lambda syntax that matters here, but actually what I needed was to realize this None convention of PyQt. Thanks.

Comment: @EMS: Er, there are no PyQt conventions here, it's all basic Python. Both `self.updateGroupComments(...)` and `lambda: self.updateGroupComments(...)` are valid Python expressions — except the first one calls `updateGroupComments` immediately (just like you're calling `self.connect`) and the other one creates a function that will call `updateGroupComments`. Play in an interactive interpreter with it (on simpler examples, and without PyQt).

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. There was at no point any confusion over the difference between self.updateGroupComments(...) and lambda: self.updateGroupComments(...) as Python expression. My question was why does the PyQt function connect() disallow as a slot the immediate function call self.updateGroupComments(...) with a named argument (this gives an error if you put self.updateGroupComments(my_args) as an argument to connect() without the preceding lambda:).

Comment: @EMS: Well, because signals and slots are all about deferred calls, that's why the last argument has to be callable. `self.connect(foo, SIGNAL('foo()'), self.something())` is equivalent to `result = self.something(); self.connect(foo, SIGNAL('foo()'), result)` — there is nothing `connect` can allow or disallow — it only knows about the objects it receives, not where they came from. And if `result` is not callable, then you get the error. Whether the function takes arguments or not is orthogonal to the issue.